# How can I read messages in a Gmail account from Perl?

Tags: perl

I have used the module [Mail::Webmail::Gmail](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-Webmail-Gmail) to read the new messages in my Gmail account.

I have written the following code for this purpose:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Mail::Webmail::Gmail;

my $gmail = Mail::Webmail::Gmail->new(
    username => 'username', password => 'password',
);


my $messages = $gmail->get_messages( label => $Mail::Webmail::Gmail::FOLDERS{ 'INBOX' } );


foreach ( @{ $messages } ) {
    if ( $_->{ 'new' } ) {
        print "Subject: " . $_->{ 'subject' } . " / Blurb: " . $_->{ 'blurb' } . "\n";
    }
}
```

But it didn't print anything.

Can anyone help me in this or suggest any other module for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the reviews ( http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Mail-Webmail-Gmail ) and the bugs ( https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Mail-Webmail-Gmail ) it might be that the module simply doesn't work. As one of them comments, GMail provides a POP3 (and an IMAP) interface now, so you would probably be better off using one of those.

Comment: Agreed; I have a gmail/Google Apps email account and I pull it down with fetchmail using a SSL certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Mail::POP3Client](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-POP3Client) module. It is used to get the message from the Gmail account.

Comment: IMAP is usually a better alternative, thanks for the info anyway (was in 2010, I see ;-)

Answer (score 7):

This is taken almost word from word from the Net::IMAP::Simple POD:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# required modules
use Net::IMAP::Simple;
use Email::Simple;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

# fill in your details here
my $username = 'user@example.com';
my $password = 'secret';
my $mailhost = 'pop.gmail.com';

# Connect
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple->new(
    $mailhost,
    port    => 993,
    use_ssl => 1,
) || die "Unable to connect to IMAP: $Net::IMAP::Simple::errstr\n";

# Log in
if ( !$imap->login( $username, $password ) ) {
    print STDERR "Login failed: " . $imap->errstr . "\n";
    exit(64);
}
# Look in the INBOX
my $nm = $imap->select('INBOX');

# How many messages are there?
my ($unseen, $recent, $num_messages) = $imap->status();
print "unseen: $unseen, recent: $recent, total: $num_messages\n\n";


## Iterate through unseen messages
for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= $nm ; $i++ ) {
    if ( $imap->seen($i) ) {
        next;
    }
    else {
    my $es = Email::Simple->new( join '', @{ $imap->top($i) } );

    printf( "[%03d] %s\n\t%s\n", $i, $es->header('From'), $es->header('Subject') );
    }
}


# Disconnect
$imap->quit;

exit;
```

Comment: This is a lot better approach than using POP3 as in the accepted answer. Also, Gmail by default has POP3 disabled.

Comment: @JeffHolt Maybe this is the probem https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/

Comment: @JeffHolt That's interesting, thanks. Have another app that worked (declared as "less secure") but I had to use it only once (to do some many-emails processing), so maybe the same problem would occur...

Comment: @e2-e4 I just now tried enabling less secure apps and KennV's solution works. Not sure why my prior attempt failed. And, of course, I don't know if it will continue to work.

Comment: @JeffHolt Please try again in a few days and let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing some error checking with after you try an operation

```
if ($gmail->error())
{
    print $gmail->error_msg();
}
```

I found that when I do it it results in:

> Error: Could not login with those
>   credentials - could not find final URL
>   Additionally, HTTP error: 200 OK
>   Error: Could not Login.

I believe it may be because this module was last updated in 2006 and gmail may have changed the way the logins work so it may no longer be able to access it.

What you could do if you don't just want to download new messages with pop3 is you can use 
[Net::IMAP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~JPAF/Net-IMAP-Simple-0.93/Simple.pm) to access a gmail account via IMAP