# How can I read the body of a messages in a Gmail account from Perl?

Tags: perl, gmail-imap

I have readed what was posted 3 years ago here -> [How can I read messages in a Gmail account from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528510/how-can-i-read-messages-in-a-gmail-account-from-perl)

But i can't open the body .. i've readed Net::IMAP::Simple and Email::Simple; . I'm trying this.. but doesn't works, it prints de from and the subject, but not the body.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# required modules
use Net::IMAP::Simple;
use Email::Simple;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

# fill in your details here
my $username = 'email@gmail.com';
my $password = 'pass';
my $mailhost = 'imap.gmail.com';

# Connect
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple->new(
    $mailhost,
    port    => 993,
    use_ssl => 1,
) || die "Unable to connect to IMAP: $Net::IMAP::Simple::errstr\n";

# Log in
if ( !$imap->login( $username, $password ) ) {
    print STDERR "Login failed: " . $imap->errstr . "\n";
    exit(64);
}
# Look in the INBOX
my $nm = $imap->select('INBOX');

# How many messages are there?
my ($unseen, $recent, $num_messages) = $imap->status();
print "unseen: $unseen, recent: $recent, total: $num_messages\n\n";


## Iterate through unseen messages
for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= $nm ; $i++ ) {
    if ( $imap->seen($i) ) {
        next;
    }
    else {
    my $es = Email::Simple->new( join '', @{ $imap->top($i) } );
    my $text = $es->body;
    printf( "[%03d] %s\n\t%s\n%s", $i, $es->header('From'), $es->header('Subject'),$text);
    }
}


# Disconnect
$imap->quit;

exit;
```

This print:

```
[001] <example@example.com>
     test subject
```

Not the body of the email.

Can anyone solve this???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Excuse me. When i say doesn't works, i mean there's no results. I see the from and subject, but not the body.

Comment: `$es->body;` vs `es->body`  does that fix it.

Comment: "No results" meaning nothing is printed?  That `printf` statement must have printed something, even if it was empty brackets and some whitespace.  Are you sure that block of code is even executing?  What is in the `$es` object?  After the instantiation of `$es`, add this: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($es);` and see what you get.

Comment: Assuming @Doon's suggestion fixes it, it tells me that the program doesn't have `use warnings; use strict;` at the top of it, which would have caught the problem.  Your Perl programs should always have `use warnings; use strict;` at the top.

Comment: I use warnings and strict. I was trying to explain, that the program print the from and the subject but not the body of the email

Comment: is the code you posted above a cut and pastes, since the bare `es` could be the cause of your issue,  but @AndyLester's dumper command should help debug if that isn't the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using:

```
$imap->top($i)
```

From [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jettero/Net-IMAP-Simple-1.2201/Simple.pod) (emphasis mine):

> This method accepts a message number as its required parameter. That
>   message will be retrieved from the currently selected folder. On
>   success this method returns a list reference **containing the lines of
>   the header**. Nothing is returned on failure and the errstr() error
>   handler is set with the error message.

`top` doesn't return the body of the message.  You'll need to use `get` for that.  Something like this:

```
my $es = Email::Simple->new( join '', @{ $imap->get($i) } );
                                                ^^^
```